# ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChange after login and logout

Tags: angular

After logging in through my angular app i get the following error

```
LoginComponent.html:9 ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
at viewDestroyedError (core.js:9783)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14635)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13785)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15039)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14576)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11560)
at eval (flash-messages.component.js:39)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4724)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
```

I tried the answers given on stack overflow and github but non is working for me.Even after logout i'm getting this error.
This is my login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit ,OnDestroy 
,ChangeDetectorRef,ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import { UserLogs } from '../../model/UserLog';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit ,OnDestroy {
  user:UserLogs;

  constructor(private authService :AuthService,
   private router:Router,
    private flashMsg : FlashMessagesService,private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.user={ntid:"",password:""};
    this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth =>{
      console.log(this.authService.who);

      if(auth)
      {
        console.log('logged in '+localStorage.getItem("token"));

        if(localStorage.getItem("token")=="user")
        {
          this.router.navigate(['/chat']);
        }
        else if(localStorage.getItem("token")=="consultant"){
          this.router.navigate(['/consultant']);
        }
      }
      else{
        console.log('Logged out');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    })
  }
  ngOnChanges(values) {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
  onSubmit({value,valid}:{value:UserLogs,valid:boolean}){
    localStorage.setItem("token", "user");
    this.authService.login(value.ntid+'@gmail.com',value.password,"user")
    .then(res =>{

      this.flashMsg.show('You are now logged in',
        {cssClass:'alert-success',timeout : 4000});

        this.router.navigate(['/chat']);
      }).catch(err =>{
        this.flashMsg.show(err.message,
        {cssClass:'alert-danger',timeout : 4000});
      })

  }
  onSubmit1({value,valid}:{value:UserLogs,valid:boolean}){
    localStorage.setItem("token", "consultant");
    this.authService.login(value.ntid+'@gmail.com',value.password,"consultant")
    .then(res =>{

      this.flashMsg.show('You are now logged in',
        {cssClass:'alert-success',timeout : 4000});

        this.router.navigate(['/consultant']);
      }).catch(err =>{
        this.flashMsg.show(err.message,
        {cssClass:'alert-danger',timeout : 4000});
      })

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
      }
}
```

and this is my login.component.html file

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
      <flash-messages></flash-messages>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="text-center pb-4 pt-3" style="color:#406E8E">
          <span class="text-info"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>User</span> Login</h1>
      <form #loginForm="ngForm" >
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <label for="ntID">Username</label>
          <input type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="user.ntid"
            name="ntid"
            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':ntid.errors && ntid.touched}"
            #ntid="ngModel"
            required
            minlength="7"
           placeholder="NTID" class="form-control z-depth-5 " id="email">
           <div [hidden]="!ntid.errors?.required"
              class="invalid-feedback">Username required
            </div>
            <div [hidden]="!ntid.errors?.minlength"
              class="invalid-feedback">Must be atleast 7 characters
            </div>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control z-depth-5 "
            [(ngModel)]="user.password"
            name="password"
            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':password.errors && password.touched}"
            #password="ngModel"
            required>
            <div [hidden]="!password.errors?.required"
              class="invalid-feedback">Password is required
            </div>
          </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg btn-block mb-4" id="signInBtn" (click)="onSubmit(loginForm)"
         >Login as user</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-4" id="signInBtn1" (click)="onSubmit1(loginForm)">
          Login as consultant</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I tried many solutions and some of them are there in the code too.So,if my approach is wrong then i'm sorry,i'm new to angular so i'm not able to solve this problem.